# Google Cloud Functions: How do you share source code?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a Node server and multiple controllers that perform DB operations and helpers (For e-mail, for example) within that directory.

I'd like to use source from that directory within my functions. Assuming the following directory structure:

```
src/
  server/
    /app/controllers/email_helper.js
  fns/
    send-confirm/
```

What's the best way to use `email_helper` within the send-confirm function?

I've tried:

- Symbolically linking the 'server' directory
- Adding a local repo to send-confirm/package.json

Neither of the above work.

Answer (score 9):

In principle, your Cloud Functions can use any other Node.js module, the same way any standard Node.js server would. However, since Cloud Functions needs to build your module in the cloud, it needs to be able to locate those dependency modules from the cloud. This is where the issue lies.

Cloud Functions can load modules from any one of these places:

- Any public npm repository.
- Any web-visible URL.
- Anywhere in the `functions/` directory that `firebase init` generates for you, and which gets uploaded on `firebase deploy`.

In your case, from the perspective of `functions/package.json`, the `../server/` directory doesn't fall under any of those categories, and so Cloud Functions can't use your module. Unfortunately, `firebase deploy` doesn't follow symlinks, which is why that solution doesn't work.

I see two possible immediate fixes:

- Move your `server/` directory to be under `functions/`. I realize this isn't the prettiest directory layout, but it's the easiest fix while hacking. In `functions/package.json` you can then have a local dependency on `./server`.
- Expose your code behind a URL somewhere. For example, you could package up a `.tar` and put that on Google Drive, or on Firebase Cloud Storage. Alternatively, you can use a public git repository.

In the future, I'd love it if `firebase deploy` followed symlinks. I've filed a feature request for that in Firebase's internal bug tracker.

Comment: This is similar to what I did with FireMail -
 https://github.com/vdsabev/firemail/tree/89bd77f803ba941a017aadcb041cba0b3298e585 - I wrote a function factory in `./functions/sendMail.js`, then used it it in both `./functions/index.js` and `./index.js`. This allows me to write the `sendMail` function without depending on firebase at all, and also makes it easier to test.

Comment: Deploying might follow symlinks to files but not directories, by the way - which seems to be the case across google's deploy infrastructure.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. I have some common code used by my front end, my Google Cloud functions, and also my Docker back-end. GCF and Docker both don't follow symlinks. I wish there was a good solution for this -- it's a pain! At least with Docker you can explicitly create the context with `tar -czh . | docker build -` but GCF doesn't allow that either.