# How to share code between client and cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I have a class which is useful in both sides, the client and the backend (GCFs).

I have thought to create a directory "shared" in which I write all classes/modules that are shared between both sides, like this:

```
app/

shared/

functions/
```

My question is, would I be able to use code from 'shared' in a cloud function? Because I read before that all the code has to be inside the functions directory...

Or do I have to duplicate the class in app/ and functions/ ?

Comment: Interesting topic. I understand you want to do changes in shared code only once. Can you add little more details about your architecture? How do you deploy the cloud function and how do you deploy your app?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842018/google-cloud-functions-how-do-you-share-source-code